# Proof on Fubini's Theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

The Fubini's Theorem states that for any two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(S,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and $(T,\mathcal{T},\upsilon)$, there exists a unique measure $(\mu \otimes \upsilon)(A\times B)=\mu A \cdot \upsilon B$, $\forall A\in\mathcal{S},B\in\mathcal{T}$.
Further more, for any measurable function $f:S\times T\rightarrow\Bbb{R}_+$,
$$(\mu\otimes\upsilon)f=\int\mu(ds)\int f(s,t)\upsilon(dt)=\int\upsilon(dt)\int f(s,t)\mu(ds)$$
Prove the following:
$$\Bbb{E}(\xi^p)=p\int^{\infty}_0 P(\xi>t)t^{p-1}dt$$
Where $\xi$ is a non-negative random varibale and $\xi^p=p\int^{\infty}_0 1\{t<\xi\}t^{p-1}dt$.
Can someone e give me some hints on the proof ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is any way around showing it first for simple functions, then for a general non-negative function and then for a general function.

Comment: Can u give me some hints?

Comment: Hmm, are you asking for help on how to show Fubini's theorem or the other thing?

Comment: I mean the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\Bbb E(\xi^p) =
&
\int \xi^p \, \mathrm d P
\\
=
& 
\int \left( \int_0^\infty 1_{\{t < \xi\}}pt^{p-1} \,\mathrm dt\right)\,\mathrm d P
\\
=
&
 \int_0^\infty \left( \int 1_{\{t < \xi\}}pt^{p-1} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt
\\
=
&
 \int_0^\infty \left( \int_{\{t < \xi\}}pt^{p-1} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt
\\
=
&
 \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} \left( \int_{\{t < \xi\}} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt
\\
=
&
 \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} P(t < \xi) \,\mathrm dt
\\
\end{align}

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty \left( \int 1_{\{t < \xi\}}pt^{p-1} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt
=\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} \left( \int1_{\{t < \xi\}} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt
$$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Steven yes. It's right.

Answer (score 3):

We have, just expanding the definitions:

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb E(\xi^p) &= \int \xi^p \, \mathrm dP = \int \left(p \int_0^\infty 1_{\{t < \xi\}}t^{p-1} \,\mathrm dt\right)\,\mathrm dP
\end{align}$$

Can you see what Fubini's Theorem has to do with this?

Comment: $\xi^p = p \int_{0}^\infty 1_{\{t \lt \xi\}} t^{p-1}\,\mathrm dt$ is *not* a definition.

Comment: @Martin: I am just quoting OP there...

Comment: I can see that. However, understanding this identity is the whole point of the exercise, isn't it?

Comment: @Lord_Farin $\int_0^\infty \left( \int 1_{\{t < \xi\}}pt^{p-1} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt
=\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} \left( \int1_{\{t < \xi\}} \,\mathrm d P \right) \,\mathrm dt$ correct?

Comment: @Martin: I'm not to judge. For all we could know, this could be a follow-up question to "Show $\xi^p = \ldots$". Steven: Yes.